# wmv動画の"Format"と"Codec"の違いについて教えてください(MediaInfoで確認）

Tags: wmv, mediainfo

## 背景

以下は、wmv動画の詳細情報を、[MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)で確認した結果です。

```
General
Complete name                            : original-480p.wmv
Format                                   : Windows Media
File size                                : 228 KiB
Duration                                 : 8 s 85 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 232 kb/s
Maximum Overall bit rate                 : 249 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2020-09-26 14:04:15.550
MediaFoundationVersion                   : 2.112

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : VC-1
Codec ID                                 : WMV3
Codec ID/Info                            : Windows Media Video 9
Codec ID/Hint                            : WMV3
```

## 質問

Video情報の以下の項目の違いを教えていただきたいです。

- Format
- Codec ID
- Codec ID/Info
- Codec ID/Hint

### 質問1：FormatとCodecの違いについて

"VC-1"のWikipediaでの情報は、以下の通りです。

> VC-1（ブイシーワン）は、マイクロソフトが開発した動画像圧縮方式であるWindows Media Video 9を規格化したものである。
> https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC-1 引用

動画圧縮方式の規格化とは何でしょうか？「VC-1」が規格なら、「VC-1」の実装方法が「WMV3」以外にあるのでしょうか？

mp4動画をMediaInfoで開くと、"Format"情報だけで"Codec"情報はないので、疑問に思いました。

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
```

### 質問2: WMV3とWindows Media Video 9について

WMV3とWindows Media Video9は同じ意味なのでしょうか？
その場合、"Windows Media Video9"が正しい名前なのでしょうか？

また、"Codec ID/Hint"は、どこで使われる情報なのでしょうか？"ID"と"Info"の対応は何となくわかるのですが、"Hint"がどこで使われるのかが分かりませんでした。

## 参考にしたサイト

https://www.wdic.org/w/TECH/Windows%20Media%20Video
https://okwave.jp/qa/q7131592.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 日本語訳

- Format：フォーマットを表すための技術的な名前です。すべてのコンテナで共通して使われます。AVI、WMV、MP4 など。
- CodecID：demuxer 用にフォーマットを表すための識別子です。コンテナ固有のもので、同じフォーマットに対して異なる識別子が用いられることもあります。互換性のために重要です（動画再生ソフトが、あるフォーマットに対応する識別子 1 は知っているものの同じフォーマットに対応する識別子 2 は知らないため、あるファイルは再生できるのに、同じ動画フォーマットを使っているはずの別のファイルは再生できないなんてことが時々あります）。
- Info：フォーマットの詳細や、フォーマットを表す長い名前です。
- Hint：特別な場合のためのヒント（補足的な情報）です。たとえば MPEG-4 Visual ファイルは DivX としても知られているため、ヒントに DivX と書かれます。「WMV3」というヒントは無駄ですから、削除するつもりです。

Jérôme（MediaInfo の開発者です）

<sub>-- この回答は英語で書かれていたため、コミュニティによって和訳されました。以下に原文を残します。</sub>

### 原文

- Format: the technical format name, common to all containers (AVI, WMV, MP4...).
- CodecID: identifier used for indicating to a demuxer what is the format, specific by container, and you may have several identifiers for the same format, so it is important for compatibility (sometimes a player knows that an identifier 1 is for a format, but is not aware that identifier 2 is also for the same format so the player will play one file but not the other even if the video format is same).
- Info: just more details or long form of a format.
- Hint: just an hint for some special cases e.g. some MPEG-4 Visual files were also know as DivX so DivX is written there, obviously the hint "WMV3" is useless, I'll remove it.

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo (sorry for the answer in English, but I don't speak Japanese, if some people can translate the answer in Japanese...)